# how to deal with numbers in camelcase naming policy?

Tags: naming-conventions

Can anyone tell me how to rename variables like **play_size_32**,**play_url_24_m4a** in camelcase naming policy? I am deserializing json string, but I don't know how to deal with such variable names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
playSize32, playUrl24M4a
```

I agree that camel case is not great when dealing with numbers, you should try to avoid variables names containing them

Comment: Well, it seems that I have to use gson annotations like _@SerializedName("play_size_32")_ to solve this problem.

Comment: The real problem is to differentiate like `exercise_1_11` and `exercise_11_1`

Comment: @aafulei  I've seen it recommended to replace the underscore ( `_` ) with an easy-to-identify letter like `p`. _e.g._ `exercise_11_1  --> exercisep11p1`   (perhaps that helps?)